# How to use Airflow-API-Plugin?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I want to List and Trigger DAGs using this https://github.com/airflow-plugins/airflow_api_plugin  github repo. How and where should I place this plugin in my `airflow` folder so that I can call the endpoints?

Is there anything that I need to change in the `airflow.cfg` file?

Answer (score 0):

The repository you listed has not been updated in a while. Why not just use the experimental REST APIs included in Airflow? You can find them here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/api.html .

Use:

> GET /api/experimental/dags//dag_runs

to get a list of DAG runs and

> POST /api/experimental/dags//dag_runs

to trigger a new dag run

Comment: ```GET /api/experimental/dags/dag_runs``` . This doesn't work. There is an API to list Latest runs - ```GET /api/experimental/latest_runs```. And to Trigger a DAG ```POST /api/experimental/dags/dag_id/dag_runs``` -  But , this one is not working. It says method not allowed. And the REST API REFERENCE also says **The API structure is not stable. We expect the endpoint definitions to change.**